# how to solve "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ "

Tags: json, error-handling, java.lang.class

I'm facing problem when I run the app on my mobile and when I run the error with stack trace or with debug option there is no error so I don't know what to do 
Here's the error message

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path` $

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your model is expecting a JSON array value but was surprised by a String value so it threw an exception. You can solve this in two different ways:

1- Edit your API response to return an empty JSON array or a JSON array with only one value in it. I mean always wrap your response value in a JSON array.

2- Edit your model to accept all data types, you can use Object as the data type for this value then cast it to an array or to a single value only.

Hope this helps, happy coding!